# How to implement ::find() and ::count() from a header file in C++?

Tags: c++, count, find

I'm trying to implement a stack class from the header file.
I've written it using 3 files- stack.h, stack.cpp and main.cpp.

To find an element, I'm using the following code in stack.cpp.

```
bool stack::find (const string &elem) const
{
    vector<string>::const_iterator it = _stack.begin();
    return ::find(it,_stack.end(),elem))!=_stack.end();
}
```

However, find keeps returning false all the time. I'm getting 'word not found' each time.
Can you please help me with this?

Here is the pastebin link for the code: [PasteBin Link](http://pastebin.com/if37zDYv)

Comment: I'm not sure how those brackets in the return work out, but the comparison should be inside.

Comment: Um, I may be misunderstanding the question, but is there something wrong with std::stack?

Comment: How is `::find` defined?

Comment: @Avi `std::stack` has no easy way to perform lookup.

Comment: find() is not defined. I'm using #include<algorithm>

Comment: A class called `stack`, methods called `find`, plus `using namespace std` is just asking for trouble.

Comment: There's a reason there's no easy way to do lookup in a stack: you'd have to pop potentially the entire stack. If you're trying to do lookup, you want a different data structure.

Comment: @Avi exactly, so it looks like OP is implementing a stack with lookup. I am not saying makes sense...

Comment: But _stack is a vector<string>. And basically, I'm using iterator to find word. So it doesn't work? This is how it has been given in "essential C++" by Stanley Lippman

Comment: @Crocode there is too much broken in your code to say for sure. Post a small, self-contained example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza yeah, sorry, that wasn't in response to you.

Comment: The problem is in the code you are not showing. It "works" after some minor fixes: http://ideone.com/E6JBy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing an iterative lookup, a stack isn't the data structure you want to use. The point of a stack is that you have to pop off the elements to access them. If you're going through all of the elements in a search, the only way to preserve the state of the stack is to save all of the elements in a separate container and push them back onto the stack after the search is done. And if you're doing that, why not just use a random access container like std::vector?

So the answer to your questions is: don't do that, us a different container.

Comment: Ok thank you. I was just learning to implement classes and this was an example given in the book. It performs all the operations of stack except find and count. And it is a std::vector<string>.